# Graph average distance

Tags: graph-theory

I can't seem to figure out the formula behind the function mean_distance from igraph for a directed and weigthed graph.

If the output for distances(n) is:

```
  0   2   3   3
  2   0   1   1 
  3   1   0   2 
  3   1   2   0
```

Then the result for mean_distance(n) is 1.

I can't reach that value doing the math by myself without using the function mean_distance.

Can someone tell me the mathematic formula behind this?

Comment: Why do you think mean_distance is 1?

Comment: it's the result with the package igraph in R

Comment: https://igraph.org/r/html/latest/distances.html: `mean_distance` "does not consider edge weights currently".

Comment: thank you so much!!!

Comment: @Tata, How is about the mathematical formula?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose, that $G=(V,E)$ is a directed graph with vertex set $V=V(G)$ and egde set $E=E(G)$. If $G$ is connected, therefore, the average distance $\mu(G)$ [1] is defined to be the average of all distances in $G$:
$$
\mu(G)=\frac{\sum_{(u,v)\in{V\times{V}}}{d_G(u,v)}}{n(n-1)}.
$$

1. Peter Dankelmann, "Minimum average distance of strong orientations of graphs", May 2004, "Discrete Applied Mathematics", 143.

Comment: But wouldn't that formula equal to a mean_distance of 2?

Comment: Being a directed graph d(1,2) != d(2,1). So I don't understand why it isn't (2+3+3+1+1+2+2+3+3+1+1+2)/12=2